# how to get previous day date in unix/SunOS

Tags: date, unix, sunos

I am using below code

```
TZ=Etc/GMT+169 date  '+%m/%d/%Y'
```

but above code print the current date 
the Idea is I want to go behind 7+ more days in unix system for that I am just adding 24 to GMT It is working for 6 days only. If I increase GMT value after 169 it is printing current date.
[image]

Comment: `date -d yesterday` available?

Comment: -d options is not available in sunOs